# Authentication between Windows AD and Linux LDAP Server and google APPS

Tags: active-directory, ldap, google

- I have an active directory instance hosted in a secure data center offsite. That active directory allows my sharepoint users to have authentication
- I have google apps for all my users in the organization for email, etc... I do have jira hooked to google apps for authentication
- I have onsite, mostly linux servers, and just windows clients.

[image]

I want to be able to keep all these system sync, so users have a unified username and password.

thus far, I can setup the DirSyncGoogleApps plugin, to keep sync of google's LDAP with AD, but what makes sense for my linux servers and windows clients? I'd like pointers on how to unify this infrastructure.